# List Item won't save if title is entered

Tags: 2010, web-part, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a new list and am working on editing the newform.aspx page to customize the form. In the new list, I have renamed the title column to 'Details' because I will be using it as a link to view the individual item details.

The form to create a new item works perfectly unless a value is specified for the Details column. If no value is entered, the item saves and the Details column will have a value of "(no title)" but if a value is entered in the field, clicking save just seems to refresh the page and the item won't save. I have tried removing the Details field from the form and setting a default value of 'View Details' but the item still would not save.

The base form was created by SharePoint Designer by using the Insert-->SharePoint-->Custom List Form option and selecting the new list so everything should be mapped correctly. If anyone has any idea what might be causing this, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Renaming the Title column isn't generally recommended; it's been known to cause a variety of issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to rename the title column but if you rename this column then you have to use the internal name(Title) for coding because you can not change the internal name of that column

[How to change internal field name(column name) of sharepoint list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54127/how-to-change-internal-field-namecolumn-name-of-sharepoint-list/54128#54128)