# How to change internal field name(column name) of sharepoint list?

Tags: splist

Can we direct change it from sql database?
if yes then how?

or

any other solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, you can not change internal name of column. You have to delete old column and create new column if you want to change column name

Comment: you are always welcome

Comment: It's worth adding to Rajesh's answer, that in no way, shape or form, should you ever edit any SharePoint configuration or content databases directly in SQL. Database level changes are not supported, which is why Microsoft gives us multiple APIs to manage and manipulate the system.

Comment: Yeah but changing a list name and having the name not update in the backend? Completely ludicrous and poor programming.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I don't know what will happen if you do it, but you can change just about **anything** using [SharePoint Manager](http://www.keutmann.dk/Products.aspx) (it is called "2007" but works fine in "2010").  The **Internal Name** I think is the same as `StaticName`.  In SharePoint Manager, if the value of the field is not grayed out, you can change it.  Be sure to push the "save" button in the toolbar.

Again, I have never done this, and don't know what will happen if you do!

However, I *have* used this trick to enable the delete button on a particularly dastardly column that I could not otherwise remove.  Worked like a charm, too!

[image]

Comment: I'd be very hesitant to do this unless you have a full backup.

Comment: Those types of changes are definitely unsupported. The static name doesn't change because of SharePoint's reliance on that name being consistent for the benefit of other parts of the system. As @KitMenke said, I definitely wouldn't dork around with it in SPM.

Comment: Agreed, completely.  I don't advocate this. I was only showing the possibility.

Comment: The static name is *not* the same as the internal name. The static name can be changed, the internal name cannot. The internal name will remain the same, even if you change the static name.

Also, SharePoint Manager is just a tool that uses the same APIs that are available to you. There's no magic going on.

Comment: EntityPropertyName is Rest API name that i want to change it. Is there any program or sources on github that get oldfieldname and newfieldname and list name then copy all data to new generated filed ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to name column for e.g. _dlc_static_Name_cat save filed later edit field and change name e.g. Cat in caml editor you will see that column name internal is _dlc_static_Name_cat and display Cat

Answer (score 1):

when you have reports that connected to this datas

or

when we have same internal name like **year** and want to use site column for example : **Year** and SharePoint Entity internal name set **Year0** with zero added unwanted character

you have harder way:

1. Copy field data to new tempField by Access or etc.
2. delete oldfield
3. create new one by your desired name
4. copy from tempField to new by Microsoft Access