# Renamed List Column - List Items Are Still Returning With Old Property

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, rename

Disclaimer - Forgive me. I am a Sharepoint novice and have picked up this project from someone else. I'm stumbling my way though.

I have a list of items called 'Ideas', in this list was a column called 'Areas', I have renamed this list to 'Category' through Sharepoint Designers 'Edit Columns' feature.

However, when I attempt to retrieve this property via: `idea.get_item('Category')` I receive the following error:

`The property of field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

If I change my get_item call back to `idea.get_item('Area')` it works as expected.

What have I missed?

Comment: This is because changing the column title/name doesn't change the internal field name.  and there is no way to change internal name: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54127/how-to-change-internal-field-namecolumn-name-of-sharepoint-list

Comment: As a workaround, you can save the list as a template (including content) and then make a new list (with correct name) using the list template.